# How to open PDF-file locked by password?

Tags: pdf, okular

I discovered a PDF-file in my home directory apparently generated 2 years ago, of which I have no recollection how it got there; all my attempt to open it by using either "okular"  or "acroread"  failed. A little window opens up, which demands "Please enter the password to read the document". I've never generated files with password -- simply don't know how this is done. A reply to a command "ls -ls" applied to that file reads "96 -rw-rw-r-- 1 " I've tried "chmod" with various options, and got no positive results. How can I read that funny file?

Comment: If you didn’t generate it and don’t know the password, just delete it.

Comment: PDF files may be password protected by its creator, in which case their content becomes encrypted, giving you only two options to unlock them: either by entering the correct password, or attempting to "crack" (sc. brute force) it. The latter may be a very time-consuming and possibly morally dubious course of action. If you don't remember the contents of the file or whether it was truly yours, it might be best to leave it alone or remove it.

Comment: The thing is that I damn don't remember whether I generated it (by possibly encrypting it in some  error...) BTW, I installed now "qpdf" command by using "sudo apt-get install qpdf", and then using "qpdf --decrypt  BAD.pdf GOOD.pdf". It didn't work either...

Comment: Even `qpdf` needs a password, that unfortunately you haven't.

Comment: thanks, folks... I guess I better remove it, sigh... otherwise, curiosity may kill the cat, right?